# msgpack: RangeError when decoding data

Tags: sh, msgpack

In the link below, I was trying to decode data encoded by msgpack but this error happens:
`Uncaught RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView`

Link:
https://repl.it/@programmeruser/weblinux#main.sh